# Unable To set The Visibility property of the pivotItem Class

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have an Excel file,created Pivot and Two filter (Principal vendor Name and date)when am filtering by name

I would like to filter each Principal vendor Name, At a time only one value in the filter should be selected other should deselected
I tried this Code.

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("3rd Pivot")

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("secondpivot_table")
    
    Dim pF As PivotField

    Set pF = pt.PivotFields("Principal Vendor Name")

    pF.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    pF.CurrentPage = "(All)"
    
    For i = 1 To pF.PivotItems.Count

    pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
     
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    k = i
    For j = 1 To pF.PivotItems.Count
    pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh
  
    If i = j Then
    pF.PivotItems(k).Visible = True
    Else
    pF.PivotItems(j).Visible = False
    End If
    Next j
```

But it showing error in this line
pF.PivotItems(j).Visible = False
"Unable To set The Visiility property of the pivotItem Class"

Comment: When it fails how many items are remaining unhidden?

Comment: only first one is selected then its showing error then i put 'On Error Resume Next' but then it is selcting two values from filter (current and previous)

Comment: You can't hide an item if it's the last visible item...  It's not clear to me what your code is doing, or why you call Refresh within the loop?

Comment: so how can i change in the code?can you help me

Comment: What is the basis for hiding an item?

Comment: i saw random things on internet thats why i put refresh and all

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do though?  Which items should be hidden and which should remain visible?

Comment: just imagine in my pivot 5 options are there in the filter, after selecting the first element in the filter i need to create a new workbook with that filtername and i need to do that for each element in that filter

Comment: so when i select in the first option other should hide and so on

Comment: at a time i need only one filter

Comment: after applying one filter am creating workbook and next filter for next workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable, pF As PivotField
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("3rd Pivot")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("secondpivot_table")
    Set pF = pt.PivotFields("Principal Vendor Name")

    pF.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    pF.CurrentPage = "(All)"
    
    For i = 1 To pF.PivotItems.Count
        
        pF.PivotItems(i).Visible = True 'set the visible one first
        'then hide the rest
        For n = 1 To pF.PivotItems.Count
            If n <> i Then pF.PivotItems(n).Visible = False
        Next n
    
    Next i

End Sub
```